# Java Generics compile error in line class HanoiStack<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Stack<T>

Tags: java, generics

I come from C#, and I have no idea why Stack part of the line below is a compile error.
Can anyone help

```
public class HanoiStack<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Stack<T> throws IllegalArgumentException{
```

Comment: `FYI`: `IllegalArgumentException` is a runtime exception so it doesnt need to be declared at all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class declarations can't throw exceptions. Perhaps you meant

```
public class HanoiStack<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Stack<T> {

    public HanoiStack() throws IllegalArgumentException {
       ...  
    }
}
```

Comment: oops sure, too much C# lately and the late hour.. Thank you Reimeus